# prevent re initialization of controller on $location.path()

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am working on an application where I have to insert a back navigation link to the main page from details page. Controllers for both views are different. I am using `$location.path('/')` to navigate back to the main page. Problem is, my controller for the main page is re-initialized when I navigate back by clicking on this link, which is not the expected behavior. Is there a way to prevent re-initialisation of the controller when routing back to the same link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I had more than one apps in my angular project, It was difficult to implement answer posted above as I have my ng-view much above in hierarchy  that decides which app to be displayed to user. So, the solution is to store data inside a service. Service do not re instantiate when navigate within an app, so the data remains intact.

Inside controller,

```
// Check if data is present in service

if (service.dataModel && service.dataModel.data) {
    // insert data in scope variables here
} 

else {
   // fetch data from server and add data model to service.
}
```

Comment: The name "service" suggests a stateless piece of code. You should consider to rename you service into something like "store".

Answer (score 5):

I assume you're using AngularJS built-in routing module.  If the controller in question is associated with a route, then it will be initialized whenever the route matches a new location.  You cannot avoid it.  If you don't want a controller to be created multiple times, you should define it high up in the view hierarchy.  For example, the structure of main page could be something like this.

```
<html>
...
<body>
  <div ng-controller="SharedController">
    ...
    <ng-view></ng-view>
    ...
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, `SharedController` will be instantiated just once, regardless of which location users navigate to.  You can move `ng-view` outside the `div` occupied by `SharedController`, although that will prevent scope inheritance from working, i.e. scopes inside `ng-view` will not prototypically inherit from the scope injected into `SharedController`.

Another option is using the third-party library [`ui-router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) which introduces the concept of nested states.  With that, you could build a parent state with a controller that is instantiated just once as users access to different child states.

Comment: Thanks for comment. In my scenario it was difficult. So I resolved issue by using a service for preserving data state.

Comment: yes inject a factory/service in many controllers then they all share the same instance with values!

Comment: @Dania : You can also preserve data if you put it in `$rootScope`

Comment: Yes, storing in $rootScope could be an option, but my personal experience with AngularJs 1.x prevents me to store more and more values in $scope as it creates more overhead with more watches etc.